Accessing a RDP-share from Linux WSL
I am connecting from Linux to a Windows 11 machine via xfreerdp (RDP). As with other RDP clients, xfreerdp allows you to mount shares:
xfreerdp ~/Documents/myConfig.rdp /drive:dotfiles,dotfiles /u:AzureAD\\username
Above, I've mounted the dotfiles folder under Linux as a share under Windows. When I execute this command, the RDP session is established correctly and I can see my shared Linux dotfiles under Windows.
The point of this is that I want to have my Linux dotfiles available on Windows, so now I'd really like to access this share from WSL. I found online that I could use
sudo mkdikr /mnt/dotfileMount && sudo mount -t drvfs '\\tsclient\dotfiles' /mnt/dotfileMount (executed on the WSL shell from Windows)
Unfortunately, this command succeeds, but the /mnt/dotfileShare folder is empty. ls -a /mnt/dotfileShare shows no files.
How could I get this to work?
Random tries

Running the above with mount -v shows no error messages
Running the above on an invalid directory (-t drvfs '\\tsclient\asdf') gives an error, so the command is doing something, because using the real share (\\tsclient\dotfiles) is giving me no such error.
I rightclicked the share in Windows' file explorer and opened it in PowerShell. Indeed, the path is \\tsclient\dotfiles and an ls in PowerShell shows all the files.

System information
>wsl.exe --version

WSL version: 2.2.4.0
Kernel version: 5.15.153.1-2
WSLg version: 1.0.61
[...]
Windows version: 10.0.22631.4037


Sorry, started to comment when you originally posted, then got sidetracked with thinking there might really be a way to do this, then forgot about it, then found it again.  Short answer is that I spent a few hours on it about 6 months back and came away unsuccessful as well.
